# Angularjs: Get data response from server using custom action resource

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to get the response from the server which returns something like `true, false`, or something else, depending on the request i do, the application i am developing is using a `Restful` server i created, and just for testing purposes i made it return `true` or `false`, later i will make it return proper `json` data.

here i am trying to get the response from this code (i am not sure how to use promises yet)

```
app.service('UserService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    var self = this;

    self.login = function(credentials){
        var handler = $resource('server/web/user/access', null, {
            access: {
                method: 'POST'
            }
        });

        handler.access(credentials).$promise.then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
}]);
```

for now i am just logging what it seems to return from the server, but the log shows another promise. for now i just need to get the data so i can make the conditions, parse objects, or show data it returns from the `Restful` server

Comment: I doubt the `data` is a promise, it should be a `$resource` instance. Perhaps you're mistaking it for a promise due to the `$promise` / `$resolved` properties it will have. See the bottom of the *Usage / Returns* section here ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem here is that the `$resource` service expects either an object or array in the response and your simple Boolean value is not working correctly.

For now, you can use a response transformer to create a usable object

```
var self = this,
    handler = $resource('server/web/user/access', null, {
        access: {
            method: 'POST',
            transformResponse: function(val) {
                return {
                    val: val
                };
            }
        }
    });

self.login = function(credentials) {
    var promise = handler.access(credentials).$promise;
    promise.then(function(data) {
        $log.info(data.val);
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Comment: thank you, i didn't know i would have to do that, i thought this was already assigned in a property

Comment: @nosthertus I didn't know either :)